# Is there a way to write XSLT transformation to get only one record by emp, shift & swipeIn and Swipe Out

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I need to write an XSLT transformation for Swipe punches project. Intention is to get only one record In & Out time swipe by employee, shift & day.

Below is my XML. I want to write XSLT to get only one Swipe In (which should be first swipeIn) and one Swipe out (which should be last swipe out) in a day by Emp,Shift and Day.

But for shift: 1C change the date for swipeout since it is night shift. (night shift start from 05 PM (today) to 4 AM (tomorrow)

I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>08:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>10:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>11:10:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>12:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
        <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>14:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>18:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>    
     <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>17:30:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>19:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>20:10:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>23:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
        <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>01:30:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>03:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
        </Employees>
        <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>03:30:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>04:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
</Data>
```

Output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: This is called grouping. It even have a tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt-grouping

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in your question to associate an out time of `04:00:54` with the in time of `17:30:54` **on the previous day**.

Answer (score 0):

The main approach is a simple composite grouping on the three key values, only the night shift complicates things as then you have to group two different dates and also have to change the expressions to find the times:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>In-Time</th>
                  <th>Out-Time</th>
                  <th>EmpId</th>
                  <th>Shift</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Employees" composite="yes" 
              group-by="Empid, 
                        if (Shift != '1C') 
                        then 
                          xs:date(Date) 
                        else if (xs:time(Time) lt xs:time('08:00:00'))
                        then 
                          xs:date(Date) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
                        else 
                          xs:date(Date), 
                        Shift">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[2]}</td>
                      <td>{if (Shift != '1C')
                           then min(current-group()[InOut = 'In']/xs:time(Time))
                           else
                             min(current-group()[xs:date(Date) = current-grouping-key()[2]][InOut = 'In']/xs:time(Time))
                          }</td>
                      <td>{if (Shift != '1C')
                           then 
                             max(current-group()[InOut = 'Out']/xs:time(Time))
                           else 
                             max(current-group()[xs:date(Date) > current-grouping-key()[2]][InOut = 'Out']/xs:time(Time))}</td>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[1]}</td>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[3]}</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRAp4

This assumes the night shift is always terminated the next day, I am not sure that is realistic if someone drops out before midnight due to illness.

I have not made any attempt to format dates or times, use the various `format-date` and time functions XSLT/XPath offer.